# Limit rewritten URL length in URL Rewriter

Tags: c#, url, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, helicontech

My real url looks like this:

```
localhost/shop.asp?product=100&name=Product-name&category=cellphones
```

My rewritten url looks like:

```
localhost/cellphones/product-name/product-name_100.aspx
```

I use Helicon URL Rewriter and what i need to do is this:
If my rewritten URL exceeds 200 characters it should redirect to "Default.aspx"
Is there a rewrite rule for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ISAPI_Rewrite 3, your rule should look like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.{100} /Default.aspx [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I think `^.{100}` should be `^.{200,}` to make it match 200 characters or more.